# Invalid Selector Error: Webscraping different kinds of text from multiple spans using xpath and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape out a list of comma-separated authors with an asterisk in the following format [important]:

First Last, First Last, First Last*, First Last

The html section I am scraping is super complicated, but I've successfully tested an xpath that results in text and symbols that I want.

```
//span[@class="hlFld-ContribAuthor"]/span[@class="hlFld-ContribAuthor"]/a/text() | //span[@class="NLM_x"]/x/text() | //a[@class="ref"]/sup/text()
```

Here's the result: 
[image]

However, when I use that formula in my python code, I get an error.

My code:

```
# get authors
xpath = "//span[@class=\"hlFld-ContribAuthor\"]/span[@class=\"hlFld-ContribAuthor\"]/a/text() | //span[@class=\"NLM_x\"]/x/text() | //a[@class=\"ref\"]/sup/text()"
authors = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
print str(authors)
```

Error:

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector
>   //span[@class="hlFld-ContribAuthor"]/span[@class="hlFld-ContribAuthor"]/a/text()
>   | //span[@class="NLM_x"]/x/text() | //a[@class="ref"]/sup/text() is
>   either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error
>   occurred: InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression
>   "//span[@class="hlFld-ContribAuthor"]/span[@class="hlFld-ContribAuthor"]/a/text()
>   | //span[@class="NLM_x"]/x/text() | //a[@class="ref"]/sup/text()" is:
>   [object Text]. It should be an element.

How do I get selenium to grab the right text and symbols that I need in the right order? I haven't been able to print the results of my xpath without new lines.

EDIT: solved the xpath error by removing /text() from xpaths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `driver.find_element_by_xpath(my_xpath)` expects to find a DOM element when it locates the node identified by `my_xpath`. If it doesn't, it throws an error. Your XPath expressions all return text nodes, hence cause an error.

To return the DOM elements instead, alter your XPath expression to:

`"//span[@class=\"hlFld-ContribAuthor\"]/span[@class=\"hlFld-ContribAuthor\"]/a | //span[@class=\"NLM_x\"]/x | //a[@class=\"ref\"]/sup`"

Also, Since you are returning multiple elements, you should use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` (note plural) instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath`.

You will then be able to grab the desired text from each author element by looping over `authors`:

```
for author in authors:
    print(author.text)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works for me, except I get too many commas in my result (my actual html I'm scraping is larger than the code I used to text to xpath). I think this must be because one of my xpaths is not narrow enough in scope (the "ref" one). My results are printed on separate lines, and not as a sentence. Is there a way to fix that.

Comment: To print your output on the same line, try something like `print(' '.join([author.text for author in authors]))`

Comment: Does author.text remove spaces? I think my xpath result includes the spaces after commas ", ", however this print function does not preserve the spaces. Thanks! If I do     print (''.join([author.text.encode('utf-8') for author in authors])), I get this result First Last,First Last, andFirst Last.